# Sending gmails with php through heroku

Tags: heroku, gmail, phpmailer

So, i'm sending mails for confirmation to users that sign up. Locally i'm using phpmailer() and it all works well, my mails are sent successfully through my gmail address, but i don't know how to implement that to heroku. I found something with some ruby script, but i'm using php. Is there any way i can send emails through my gmail address using heroku?

Comment: You tagged this question with PHPMailer – have you tried using it? That it's on Heroku doesn't make much difference; so long as it can run PHP and connect to SMTP servers, that's all you need.

Answer (score 0):

This should be no different than your local setup. Install PHPMailer using composer or manual installation, then add your GMail SMTP information. Everything should work as expected if it's configured properly.

https://heroku.mailtrap.io/blog/phpmailer/

Comment: I tried again and again...it just does not work. I don't know what im doing wrong, its getting exhausting

Comment: @DragosPolifronie, "just does not work" is not a useful description. Are you getting error messages? Timeouts? In any case, I _strongly_ urge you to use something more appropriate than Gmail. It's not intended for this use case. SendGrid and Mailgun are both easy to set up and available as Heroku addons.